# Was /media mount point location a planned change?

Tags: mountpoint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure the default automount location?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214646/how-to-configure-the-default-automount-location)

I would like ask an important question regarding Ubuntu 12.10 installation on my laptop T500 ... those partitions which are not explicitly defined in fstab gets mounted to `/media/<username>/<label>`.

Is this a bug or a change made my developers.

Comment: @january the mount point is not /media but /media/<username>/<xxx>.

Answer (score 2):

The `/media` directory for temporary mount points has been here already for a while when it came to USB sticks and other removable media. I assume that this is just extending the same logic: mount the available resources to /media/xxxx, unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 2):

This is an **intentional** change made by Ubuntu developers. **It's not a bug**, `/media/<username>/<label>` is a correct location for 12.10. Earlier Ubuntu versions used `/media/<label>`.