# How do I change the automount point?

Tags: automount

In Ubuntu 12.10 automount point [has changed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201309/was-there-media-mount-point-location-or-planned-change) from /media/xyz (like was in 12.04) into 
/media/"username"/xyz.

This is a problem for me because I've my photos into an external usb HDD and Shotwell  don't find any photo when it is using a backup database.

How can I set my automount point?

I don't need to mount usb disk on startup but only in a second moment.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

1. Alt+F2 and type “gnome-disks”
2. In the "Disk Drives" list select the hard drive you want to change the automount point
3. In the "More actions..." button select "Edit Mount Options..."
4. Turn off the "Automatic Mount Options"
5. In the "Mount Point" entry, write the new mount point you wish for the disk, for example /media/Data
6. In the "Identify As" entry select /dev/disk/by-label/Data (where Data is the disk's label)
7. Click "Ok"
8. Unplug and plug the external drive again, it should be mounted to the new mount point, in this case: /media/Data

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I too noticed/faced this terrible issue.

I just did a work around by creating symlinks for the drives I use.

```
ln -s /media/<username>/xyz /media/xyz
```