# How do I mount a USB hard drive to an arbitrary mount point?

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, udev

I just upgraded my system with an SSD from a hard drive. Loads faster. But, I left all of my large media files on my hard drive. Currently, I have a SATA optical bay caddy on order, but in the meantime I can only connect my hard drive through USB (this is a laptop). I export the contents of this drive using NFS to my RaspbMC HTPC, and I'd rather not go through the trouble of changing the mountpoints all over the place. Currently, NFS exports /home/media as storing all of the media, and that's where I'd like to mount this hard drive.

The point is, currently udev and the rest work together to mount my drive at /media/$USER/Media, but I'd like to arbitrarily mount it at /home/media. **And** and like to be able to allow any user to unmount the device from the Unity panel, as they would normally with a USB thumbdrive. Having the mountpoint be consistent is important though, for NFS sake.

I know there's some kind of way with udev rules to specify this sort of thing, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

In short, **can I mount a USB HDD anywhere I like have it work as expected?**

Comment: Here's a good resource: http://scnr.net/blog/index.php/archives/132

Comment: See if [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/213457/27968) helps

Comment: Thanks @Mordoc. It actually works quite well. I'm just going to see if the "and" section of my question, being able to umount it from the unity bar, can be done somehow. If I can figure that out I may answer my own question.