# Ubuntu-MATE: make USB Sticks automount available to every user (udev rules?)

Tags: usb, mount, ubuntu-mate, udev, udisks

**I want every USB media (ext, ntfs, FAT…) inserted to be available with full read-writable to every user.** Preferably under `mnt` and as group `common`.

( Ubuntu-MATE 21.04, though my issues actually date back even to Ubuntu-MATE 16.04...)

1. I boot into my machine as user frank. When I mount an USB drive (FAT) it ends up under `/media/frank/4C8C-E4BC` – just fine, as it should. When I switch to another user (keeping the first session open, not logging off, i.e. `dm-tool switch-to-user lisa`) I get

> Unable to mount 16 GB Volume
> Device /dev/sda1 is already mounted at `/media/lisa/4C9C-xxxx`

Making sense so far. But not what I want.

Sure, for individual drives [I could change the mount location via `gnome-disks`](https://askubuntu.com/a/213457/) or manually add a line to `etc/fstab` (which essentialy is what `gnome-disks` is doing). However I do not want to do this for each and every USB stick and SD card I posess...

### **Is there a better way for an all-user automount?**

[ I understand/guess there's something [called autofs handles the automatic mounting of USB sticks?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) But as far as I can tell, that's no part of my Ubuntu-MATE install... ]

And then there seems to be [“udev-Rules”](https://askubuntu.com/a/276670), is that, what I want? Apparently it's even an “inevitable” part of Ubuntu, [as it is part of systemd (?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev#History)? There *are* rules on my machine under /etc/udev/rules.d although seemingly rather specific ones about brave and skype and signal...)

There's promising stuff `MODE` and `GROUP` and `UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED` but (provided this is the right approach) I can't set the ultimate puzzle pieces together. It should truly only apply to removable drives like USB sticks and memory cards, otherwise I get into deep trouble... [this source mentions `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"`](https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/kinetic/ros/Udev%20Rules.html), that would be a good filter, if true...)

### Is `udev` rulez the way?

If yes, can somebody set the puzzle pieces together?
I am almost suspecting all I look for is a one-liner file in /etc/udev/rules.d.

---

**addendum:**

Not my main problem, but if it went away for the same reasons, I would be happy: Inserting a Windows Boot USB Stick (slightly more commplex, comes with an UEFI Boot FAT and a Windows Install NTSF partition) under the second user, I instantly get:

[image]

(and no, intense googling didn't get me anywhere) …switching back to first user frank (stick still inserted) I am welcomed by these authorization requests:

[image]

---

**addendum:**

Not a fix, but if those two users are essentially you, and the other one is not truly active (just switched-away from instead of logged-out) this is the quickest way before a trouble-free USB mount:

```
who -u
sudo kill <that other user's pid>
```

Comment: I'm not running MATE, but other Ubuntu flavours. I don't know any way to use `udev` for this purpose, but I have used [`mount` for similar but simpler cases](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072). So I am playing with a shellscript, than can do what you want, at least with Microsoft file systems. But 1. It needs `sudo` or running as `root`. You can allow using the shellscript or `mkdir` and `mount` without password via `visudo`; 2. It is  a bad idea to tamper with the permissions in a Linux file system, e.g. `ext4`.

Comment: You should not let an automatic tool tamper with the permissions in a Linux file system because changes are persistent and might destroy system directories and configurations.. If you want to make a Linux file system available to everybody, set the permissions with `chmod`; 3.  It should work to start a shellscript manually, but it is also possible (maybe via `udev`) to watch for plugging in external devices; 4. Additinal shellscripts to unmount and clean up mountpoints should be easier to create. -- Are you interested of this `mount`way, or do you want to go the `udev` way?

Comment: I have no intend of tampering with any user rights **but** those of the volume-to-be-mounted, which is [nothing unusual in `/etc/fstab` either](https://superuser.com/q/174776). Just for 'all USB drives that may be'. (if `fstab` had some kind of wildcard-support to match USB-drives, my problem would be solved. But it doesn't.) Und Udev rules indeed also [have a `MODE` attribute](https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/kinetic/ros/Udev%20Rules.html)...

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not know `udev` well enough to help you with that. But my `mount` way *can* handle 'wild-card support'. However, you must initiate it somehow, via `cron` or `udev` or maybe some other way to watch for events. Do you want to see the script code?

Comment: yes, sure... feel free to post as an answer (more writing/viewing comfort), same goal different method, after all

Answer (score 3):

The following script may be called `mounter` or some [other] unique name.  A `for` loop looks for the output of `lsblk` with suitable options. It will detect partitions in drives connected via USB and mount them (if not already mounted) at dedicated subdirectories of /mnt.

If you want to use the shellscript in your system, you will probably tweak it to manage already mounted partitions (unmount them in order to get them mounted like you wish).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]
then
 echo "run with sudo or as root"
 exit
fi
for i in $(lsblk -lo name,fstype,hotplug,type|grep '1 part$'|tr -s ' ' ' '|sed 's/ 1 part$//'|grep ' ..*$'|tr ' ' '_')
do
 printf "$i\n"
 dev=/dev/${i%_*}
 fss=${i#*_}
# echo "$dev -- $fss"
 mkdir -p /mnt/"$i"
 if [ "$fss" == "ntfs" ] || [ "$fss" == "vfat" ] || [ "$fss" == "exfat" ]
 then
  mount -o rw,user,exec,umask=0000 "$dev" /mnt/"$i"
 else
  mount -o rw,user "$dev" /mnt/"$i"
 fi
done
```

This shellscript can do what you want, at least with Microsoft file systems.

- It needs `sudo` or running as `root`. You can allow using the shellscript or `mkdir` and `mount` without password via `visudo`.
- You may or may not want to modify the `umask` to keep 'others' from writing.
- It is a bad idea to tamper with the permissions in a Linux file system, e.g. ext4. So this shellscript uses different mount options in this case. If you want to make a Linux file system available to everybody, set the permissions with `chmod` *manually*.
- It should work to start a shellscript manually, but it is also possible via `cron` or `udev` or maybe some other way to watch for plugging in external devices.
- Additional shellscripts (or command lines) to unmount and clean up mountpoints are neceasary and should be easier to create.